# Is it possible to use HTML/Javascript to browse another website

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use HTML/Javascript to browse another website?

I am able to access a website (a wiki) using a browser. The site has a Kerberos/SSO authentication mechanism, which I am unable to log in to using anything other than Internet Explorer.

What I would like to do is to create a backup of the contents on the site recursively (it is a Wiki). I tried this with Java, but I am unable to log in. So I figured, can I create a HTML/Javascript tool that accesses the site from within IE? I tried using frames, having my tool in one frame and the Wiki in another, but that doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks, Kjeld

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: If it's a wiki, use Special:Export to export pages. More sensible would it be to create a backup on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain is not possible.
You can try this plugin: [LINK](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)

Answer (score 0):

Open on a IFrame, and then use JQuery to navigate:

```
<iframe id="site2" ...>
```

and, on jquery:

```
$('#field', '#site2')...
```